# Accessing array data through different components / pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to map `alt` from this array:

```
export const data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    id: 1,
    alt: [ name: "local fruit", description: "seasonal and stored" ]
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    id: 2,
    alt: [ name: "exotic fruit", description: "imported" ] 
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    id: 3,
    alt: [ name: "local fruit", description: "seasonal" ] 
  }
];
```

through this component:

```
export default function Accordion() {
  return (
    <>
      {data[1].alt.map((item, index) => (
        <Accordion item={item} key={index} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

and access it on this page:

```
export default function Content({ match }) {

  const item = data.find(item => item.name === match.params.itemName);

  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
        <Button item={item} light>
          {item.name.toUpperCase()}
        </Button>
        <Accordion item={item} />
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

I need to replace the hard coded index and make it dynamic - do I need to filter? Or map differently? I'm a little lost.
I am using dynamic routes (`` <Link to={`/home/${item.name}`}/> ``) to get to the page, hence the match.params.

Comment: your data array not seems ok,  alt is an array, but you put inside it like an object,  alt must be in this format     alt: [{ name: "local fruit", description: "seasonal and stored" }]

Comment: @Mina Hawker check i posted example solution of your array https://stackoverflow.com/a/58498202/6544460

Comment: @Mina Hawker check this i created sample as you want in react https://stackoverflow.com/a/58499776/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";
let data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    id: 1,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit1", description: "tbd" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    id: 2,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit2", description: "tbd" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    id: 3,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit3", description: "tbd" }]
  }
];
export default function App() {
  let output = [];
  data.map(item => output.push(...item.alt));

  return (
    <div>
      {output.map((item, i) => (
        <Accordian key={i.toString()} {...item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Accordian.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Accordian({ name, description }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} -- {description}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That works great! If I wanted to map only one ```alt``` based on the ```name```, how could I specify that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
          let data = [
      {
        name: "Apple",
        id: 1,
        alt: [{ name: "fruit1", description: "tbd" }]
      },
      {
        name: "Banana",
        id: 2,
        alt: [{ name: "fruit2", description: "tbd" }]
      },
      {
        name: "Blueberry",
        id: 3,
        alt: [{ name: "fruit3", description: "tbd" }]
      }
    ];

      let output = []
      data.map(item=>output.push(...item.alt));
      console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work for me... How would I define that inside the ```Accordion``` component and on the ```Content``` page?